# Why is it not possible to use both readonly and fixed-size buffers in structs in C# 7.2

Tags: c#, struct, unsafe, c#-7.2

With the release of C# 7.2 there is now the ability to have `readonly` structs, which in many cases can improve performance.

For one of my structs I am using a fixed-size byte array to actually hold the data. However when I marked the `struct` and the byte array field `readonly`, C# compiler complained that `readonly` is not valid on the field. Why can't I have both `fixed` and `readonly` on a field in a `struct`?

```
readonly unsafe struct MyStruct {
  readonly fixed byte _Value[6]; //The modifier 'readonly' is not valid for this item.
}
```

Comment: That has always been this way, doesn't have anything to do with 7.2.  Just consider what you are going to do with that field, hopefully you use byte* to access it.  No way for the compiler to enforce readonly on that pointer.  If you don't use byte* then there is surely a better approach, we can't tell from the question.

Comment: With C# 7.3, fixed buffers can be accessed without pinning. So I guess a compiler can disallow using `fixed` altogether for a theoretical "readonly fixed buffer" (so we can't get it as a pointer) and allow set access only in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because C# specification says so (and it always did, even before c# 7.2). In 18.7.1 section, named "Fixed size buffer declarations", the following modifiers are allowed on `fixed` buffer declaration:

> new
>
> public
>
> protected
>
> internal
>
> private
>
> unsafe

No `readonly` here. If you think about it - it doesn't make much sense anyway, because fixed buffer size is represented by a pointer, and you cannot restict write access to a pointer. For example:

```
var s = new MyStruct();
byte* value = s._Value;
// how can you prevent writing to `byte*`?
```

Comment: `it doesn't make much sense anyway` Only in the context of C# not supporting pointer-to-`const` (or in C# language, pointer-to-`readonly`). Many languages, including C and C++, do support some syntax denoting that the "pointed-to thing" is immutable, at least at compile-time. If C# allowed `readonly fixed` then it would logically decay to (the equivalent of) a `const T* const`. The pointer itself would be `const` because the buffer *already* can't be reassigned to point to something else. The missing piece that C# doesn't support (yet) is just that first `const`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a trick to have a readonly fixed field in a readonly struct:
just embed your fixed inside a dedicated struct ;-)

```
unsafe struct MyFixed {
    public fixed byte _v[6];

    public MyFixed(byte[] bs)
    {
        for (int i=0;i!=6;i++)
            _v[i]=bs[i];
    }
 }

readonly struct MyStruct {
    readonly public MyFixed Values;

    public MyStruct(byte[] bs){
        Values = new MyFixed(bs);
    }

static unsafe byte GetFixed(in MyStruct _ms)
=> _ms.Values._v[1];
        
static unsafe byte SetFixed(in MyStruct _ms)
=> _ms.Values._v[1] = 0;
```

I added:

- a constructor just to be able to test sharplab.
- Get and Set from outside, the compiler detect and report a read-only access in the Set.

This clearly demonstrate that the limitation you faced is just arbitrary and could easily be fixed (pun intended) in Roslyn ;-)

Comment: I actually used this trick recently, since having read-only structs avoid most of the hidden copies when passing said structs by 'in'.
So a useful trick, at the cost of slightly more verbose user-side code...